# iCarousel - Two-finger swipe rather than one-finger swipe

Tags: ios, swipe

I'm using iCarousel in one of my iOS projects and I must say it's an excellent piece of work.

https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel

I have a problem though - I'd like to use one-finger swipes for drawing on the UIView and two-finger swipes to switch / move between UIViews.

Is there an easy way out to achieve this ?

Cheers
Jugs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quite easy..

Just need to add this in iCarousel.m

panGesture.minimumNumberOfTouches = 2;
panGesture.maximumNumberOfTouches = 2;